# Merging two ADs - one on Office 365, the other from G-Suite to 365 - what to do?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, g-suite

We have a company merger scenario that involves two unrelated forests, one of which is using Office 365 and the other G-Suite.  The plan is to migrate the two domains and shift all of the users to Office 365.  I was curious if anyone has run into this scenario before and if so, did you migrate domains first or did you migrate mail first?  Is there a benefit to doing one before the other?

On one hand it would seem beneficial to migrate the mail first as there are more direct business needs to getting mail/calendaring working company-wide and then migrate resources into one single domain.  Are there any problems with this or is it better to take care of the domain migration first and then migrate the mail?

Are there any major caveats to either route?  It seems like Office 365 can be a single tenant for two separate forests - is a domain trust required or can they exist separately?  I'm also worried that merging the two domains after doing the Office 365 migration could pose some problems as far as securities go, but that's just a guess...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using AD Office365 integration or the Azure Active Directory? I would guess GSuite is an integration.

Sounds like you are on the right track to split the migration process into two or more stages.Fortunately, Active Directory, Office365 and GSuite can be configured to be independent of each other. I would definitely only migrate one system of users at a time. For example if Office365 is the end goal maybe get all the GSuite users using Office365 Mail first. Than proceed to getting the mail domains dns records  merged and straightened out. I would do the Active Directory on the computers last if it can keep running as is.

Comment: We'll be keeping our on-site AD and synchronizing that with Office 365.

Comment: And G-Suite is essentially an app that runs against the DCs and synchronizes certain domain objects over to Google.  Any reason for doing the domain migration last?  Also, do you know if Office 365 requires the two forests to have a trust or can they be independent of one another?

Comment: I don't know much about domain trusts or Office 365 Forests. The reason I would do the AD migration last is because Office365 is cloud based and I would want to disrupt the local user as little as possible. Migrating PC's and Users to new domains can be troublesome so I would save that for last and do the Mailboxes first. I have not had much success with merging user profiles. There are tools that can do this for you, but you may end up making new profiles for each user. Hopefully when Office365 is all setup on the Domain Outlook will find the new Office365 and  sync everything automatically.

Comment: Just checking finally what was your approach ?